# How To Loop Array with Two Samples in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop

I would like to take two constants from the array `constants` at a time because I do not want to go one by one these constants through because it is time consuming; instead, I compare the changes what they cause and only react if there is a big change between the effects of two constants. 
I am looping one sample `constant` in the array `constants` at a time in Matlab 2016a

```
constants=[45 90 180 360 720 1440 2880 5760]';
for constant=constants

...

end
```

However, I would like to take two constants at a time by one loop, like pseudocode

```
for constant1,constant2=constants

...

end
```

---

How can you take two constant(s) from `constants` in one for loop of Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
for index = 1:length(constants) - 1
    c1 = constants(index);
    c2 = constants(index + 1);
end
```

Another option is to define a function that pairs each element with the next element in the array -

```
function result = pairAdjacent(array)
    result = [array(1:end-1) ; array(2:end)];
end
```

and then do

```
for constant = pairAdjacent(constants)
    c1 = constant(1);
    c2 = constant(2);
end
```

Recall that when you use the notation

```
for elem = array
    // Now elem is a single column from array
end
```

the variable `elem` is assigned successively to each of the *columns* of `array`, so your array `constants` needs to be a 1xN array for this to work correctly.

Comment: I think the best option is the best one if there noting like your following suggestions built in by default in Matlab. Hmm ... I have x amount of operations. Using the first suggestion duplicates all these operations. Working in an array would save a lot of hassle. So I think the second version is then again the best one.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately there is nothing built in that does this.

Comment: I finally choose to use the basic modular expression for the feature, like here http://stackoverflow.com/q/35807238/54964 at the bottom. It just got too complex to create new functions and integrate them to many data structures. I think it is the simplest to have a single loop where a if clause with modular condition and isCompare.